# Why is memory usage high after calling scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm using the scipy.ndimage module to get information about labeled objects in a 3D array. I am trying to reduce the memory used by this process because it is a bottleneck limiting the number of parallel processes we can run on our compute server. I noticed that after calling the center_of_mass function, the memory usage skyrockets and does not match the size of the data returned from the function. I am calling the function like this:

```
ndimage.center_of_mass(values, labels, range(1,np.max(labels)+1))
```

The shape of `values` and `labels` is `(20, 2048, 2048)`. Before I call center_of_mass, I print out the memory usage using the resource module:

```
print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
```

Then I print it again after calling `center_of_mass`. Before, this reported `6504168` and afterwards it gives `11255620`, so the memory usage increased by almost 5 GB. But the shape of what is returned from `center_of_mass` is `(24187884, 3)` which should only require about 580 MB of memory (confirmed from checking `nbytes` on the ndarray). I am also monitoring the process with `top` and the process continues to use significantly more memory, so it isn't just a temporary spike in memory usage during the function call.

What is causing such a huge jump in memory usage? Is there any way I can reduce it?

Comment: `ndimage.center_of_mass` returns a list of tuples.  Have you turned that backing into an array?

Comment: Yes, I wrapped the function call in np.array()

Answer (score 1):

While it is easy to estimate the memory use of numpy array (essentially `nbytes`, or 8*num_elements), memory use of a list of tuples takes more work.

Lets test a 10 tuple list of random floats.

```
In [136]: import sys    
In [137]: alist = [tuple(np.random.rand(3)) for _ in range(10)]
```

The list itself  - 10 pointers plus some overhead:

```
In [138]: sys.getsizeof(alist)
Out[138]: 184
```

The size of all 10 tuples:

```
In [139]: sum([sys.getsizeof(a) for a in alist])
Out[139]: 640
```

and the floats in one of those tuples:

```
In [140]: sum([sys.getsizeof(i) for i in alist[0]])
Out[140]: 96
```

So a grand total of:

```
In [141]: 184+640+10*96
Out[141]: 1784
```

Compare that to the nbytes of the equivalent array (10,3):

```
In [142]: np.array(alist).nbytes
Out[142]: 240       # 10*3*8
```

So the list of tuples takes 7.4 times as much memory as the array.

Now scale to your (n,3) array:

```
In [143]: 24187884 * 1784/10
Out[143]: 4315118505.6    
In [144]: _/1e9
Out[144]: 4.3151185056

In [145]: 11255620-6504168
Out[145]: 4751452
```

There's your 5G

That went better than I hoped  :)

The source code for the center_maas function, found via the docs, ends with:

```
return [tuple(v) for v in numpy.array(results).T]
```

Comment: I see. So in my code, I have `result = np.array(ndimage.center_of_mass(...))` This does not result in the returned list of tuples being removed from memory once the array is created?

Comment: If used like that I expect the list to be removed, though maybe not right away.  If you did `res=ndimage.center...` followed by `print(np.shape(res)` it would stay around.